# How to connect to rabbitmq server (that its in docker container)?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, pika

I have simple rabbitmq client (its in docket container)

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('guest', 'guest')
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(host='rabbitmq_go_net', credentials=credentials))
```

try's to connect to rabbitmq server (its in other container)

but some weird errors happens

```
rayan_1     | Traceback (most recent call last):
rayan_1     |   File "/app/marketwatch_rlc/rlc_consumer.py", line 49, in <module>
rayan_1     |     start('1,MW.IRO1SIPA0001')
rayan_1     |   File "/app/marketwatch_rlc/rlc_consumer.py", line 43, in start
rayan_1     |     rlc_connection = RlcConnection(message)
rayan_1     |   File "/app/marketwatch_rlc/rlc_consumer.py", line 10, in __init__
rayan_1     |     connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
rayan_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
rayan_1     |     self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
rayan_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
rayan_1     |     raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
rayan_1     | pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
rayan_websocket_rayan_1 exited with code 1
```

*i try'ed 'rabbitmq' for host name too but i'm still get error*

and my docker compose is

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.6
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - 5673:5672
      - 15673:15672
    networks:
      - rabbitmq_go_net
  rayan:
    build: .
    networks:
      - rabbitmq_go_net
networks:
  rabbitmq_go_net:
    driver: bridge
```

and dockerfile is

```
FROM python:slim-buster
WORKDIR app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . ./
CMD python marketwatch_rlc/rlc_consumer.py
```

Comment: You did not set the port in `ConnectionParameters()` to match your Docker port mapping.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting but i used
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('guest', 'guest')
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters('rabbitmq_go_net', 5672, '/', credentials))
too
I used (5672-5673)

Comment: I guess it is impossible to connect to the `guest` account via remote connection so you must create another user account or manipulate default settings.

Comment: Thank you @meti for suggestion 
I made an other user and set root permission and administration tag
but still didn't work

Comment: According to your dockerfile, host shuld be `rabbitmq` not `rabbitmq_go_net`. More about networking in compose [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: Thank you @usuario for suggestion but i tried all possible host names also 'rabbitmq' even 'localhost' :)